# Why does my view's clustered index update when the underlying data it references doesn't change?

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

[Refer to this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/77e32/1/0) and click the "Execution Plan" link at the bottom left for context.

As you can see, the `CountryGroup` table has a single row with `CountryId = 1`. I then update the `CountryGroup` table with a statement that should effectively be a no-op (setting `CountryId = 1` when it's already 1). This triggers the rebuild of the clustered index `UX_CountryGroupView_Id` on the view, which is a relatively expensive operation (60% of the query cost). In the database I'm actually working with, the actual cost is a lot higher, hence this question.

Does SQL Server only check `@@rowcount` when determining if it should update indexes, or does/can it look at the data to see if it's changed and whether it should expend the effort of rebuilding? It seems that the former is the case, but is it possible to specify the latter behaviour, or control what SQL Server does in this circumstance?

**Please note**, I have no control over the SQL `update`statement, which is being autogenerated.

Comment: It would be an exceptionally "narrow" place for an optimization to be applied - by far the *vast* majority of updates will require some index maintenance. What is optimized is that the system shouldn't have to rebuild the entire index though - the various restrictions on indexed views exist so that maintenance is as cheap as possible.

Comment: It is not clear that this update actually causes 60% runtime cost increase. Also, physically it might not update anything. For normal indexes it does not (look at the t-log). But it needs to process the row to somehow take a lock.

Comment: @usr In my real-world scenario, with actual tables with actual data, the `update` takes under a second if the `CountryId` column is excluded, and well over a minute when that column is included. So 60% is actually on the conservative side. But regardless of that, my question/issue isn't around the time taken, it's around **how to prevent** that expensive side-effect if possible.

Comment: Would `WHERE CountryId <> 1` work?

Comment: What do you mean by "if the CountryID column is excluded"? In your example update, that's all you're affecting so there's no way to exclude it.

Comment: @BenThul In the actual query there are a bunch of other columns being updated as well as CountryID. I've updated the fiddle to reflect this.

Comment: @usr Unfortunately not - this is SQL that's being autogenerated by a homegrown Entity Framework clone (I didn't write it, but I do have to use it), so I don't have any control over what it generates. Updated question to reflect this.